# Valid JSON says invalid when part of JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, json

This is valid JSON:

```
{"query":"{actor {account(id: 1234567) {nrql(query: \"SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction SINCE 1 HOUR AGO\") {results}}}}"}
```

But If I do this as part of an HTTP POST I get an error that says invalid JSON:

```
var dataString = '{"query":"{actor {account(id: 1234567) {nrql(query: \"SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction SINCE 1 HOUR AGO\") {results}}}}"}';
```

The back slashes to escape the double quotes that make up the query should not be an issue. I have tried every combination of quotes, double quotes, escaping all double quotes within the outer single quotes, nothing works.

Comment: Except: that's not valid JSON.

Comment: Because it is basically a kind of SQL injection. No good server will allow this. Also its not a valid json

Comment: The backslashes *are* the issue. You need to escape the backslashes when putting them into a JavaScript literal.

Comment: It's invalid JSON. See yourself, JSON.parse() returns "Unexpected token S in JSON at position 53"

Comment: why are you creating JSON strings manually? Just create the actual object, then `JSON.stringify` it

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
var dataString = '{"query":"{actor {account(id: 1234567) {nrql(query: \\"SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction SINCE 1 HOUR AGO\\") {results}}}}"}';
```

2 backslashes are necessary at the boundaries of the double quotes that make up the query because the double quotes are necessary but so is the backslash itself as an escape character.